# Leer css con php

Tags: php

Me preguntaba si habría alguna forma de leer un archivo css con php y colocar los valores en input.

Por ejemplo:
tengo un input de tipo texto que se llama color y en el css tengo una linea que se llama .Cabecera. ¿Habría alguna forma de poner el texto del css en ese input?

Este es el codigo que tengo de momento, pero me lee todo el css y lo pone en un textarea.

```
$archivo = fopen($Ruta,"r") or exit;//indico archivo y que voy a hacer un read (r)
    while(!feof($archivo)) {
    $Mensaje .= fgets($archivo);
    }
fclose($archivo);

<textarea name="Contenido" id="Contenido" style="width: 99%; height: 99%; resize: none;"><?=$Mensaje; ?></textarea>
```

Yo solo quiero leer linea por linea y ponerlo en distintos input de tipo texto.

Comment: ¿Por qué no darle directamente la clase `.Cabecera` al `input`?

Comment: Aparte, ¿podrías compartir algo de lo que hayas hecho y los problemas/dificultades con las que te estés encontrando?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro de momento solo tengo como leer el css desde php. Respecto a la duda, no tengo ni una línea de código. Porque no se como se podría hacer o si se podría hacer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es lo contrario y no entiendo mal, no necesitas PHP:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <style>
            .color {
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                border: 2px solid #000000;
            }
            .verde {
                background-color: #00ff00;
            }
            .verde.claro {
                background-color: #005500;
            }
            .azul {
                background-color: #0000ff;
            }
            .azul.claro {
                background-color: #000055;
            }
            .rojo {
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
            .rojo.claro {
                background-color: #550000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 color azul claro"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 color verde claro"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 color rojo claro"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 color azul"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 color verde"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 color rojo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                    Haz clic en una caja de color: <input type="text" id="color_seleccionado">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".color").click(function(e) {
                    $("#color_seleccionado").val($(this).css("background-color"));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pero lo que yo quiero es poner dentro de un input el valor de background color. no es que quiera cambiar el aspecto del input.

Comment: Eso hace el código, seleccionas una caja de color background cualquiera y en el input aparece su valor.

Comment: ah, pues es verdad.... voy a probar con javascript :) graciiaaaas

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te sirve:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>CAMBIAR COLOR</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<h2>Cambiar color</h2>
    <p>Ingrese un color con el formato: xxxxxx, donde las xxxxxx pueden ser 0-9 y a-f</p>
    <form id="form" method="post" name="form" action="insertar.php">
        <p>Color: <input type="text" name="valor">

        <input type ="submit" value= "CAMBIAR VALOR">
        <input type="reset" value="LIMPIAR CAMPO">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**insertar.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['valor']) || $_POST['valor'] == null){
    die('Escriba un color valido');
}

$valor = $_POST['valor'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>MUESTRA</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="txt/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<style type="text/css">
html {
    background: #<?php echo $valor; ?>;
}
</style>

<body>
<h2>Hola mundo</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que lo que quiere OP es lo contrario: leer el CSS y usarlo al `input`, y no leer el valor del `input` y usarlo en el CSS. Aunque la verdad, la pregunta es algo confusa.

Comment: Oh, si es cierto compañero, a la mejor me equivoqué.

Comment: Si, como dice Alvaro lo que busco es justo lo contrario

Comment: Hágalo con JavaScript esas cosas no deben consumir.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede y es muy sencillo, lo único que tienes que hacer es desde tu código css en el archivo php (index.php por ejemplo) usar un  y listo, el valor que tienes guardado en la variable se podrá leer en el css.

Espero te sirva
Saludos

Comment: No quiero cambiar el aspecto de los input. quiero mostrar el valor que tengo almacenado en css como texto de un input